# Reading a text file in c++

Tags: c++, text, input

```
string numbers;
string fileName = "text.txt";


ifstream inputFile;
inputFile.open(fileName.c_str(),ios_base::in);
inputFile >> numbers;
inputFile.close();
cout << numbers;
```

And my text.txt file is:

```
1    2    3    4    5
```

basically a set of integers separated by tabs.

The problem is the program only reads the first integer in the text.txt file and ignores the rest for some reason. If I remove the tabs between the integers it works fine, but with tabs between them, it won't work. What causes this? As far as I know it should ignore any white space characters or am I mistaken? If so is there a better way to get each of these numbers from the text file?

Comment: It only ignores whitespace leading up to the characters. Use `std::getline` if you want the spaces included. If you want them as numbers, a `std::vector<int>(std::istream_iterator<int>(inputFile), std::istream_iterator<int>())` would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When reading formatted strings the input operator starts with ignoring leading whitespace. Then it reads non-whitespace characters up to the first space and stops. The non-whitespace characters get stored in the `std::string`. If there are only whitespace characters before the stream reaches end of file (or some error for that matter), reading fails. Thus, your program reads one "word" (in this case a number) and stops reading.

Unfortunately, you only said what you are doing and what the problems are with your approach (where you problem description failed to cover the case where reading the input fails in the first place). Here are a few things you might want to try:

1. If you want to read multiple words, you can do so, e.g., by reading all words:

   ```
   std::vector<std::string> words;
   std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(inputFile),
             std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
             std::back_inserter(words));
   ```

   This will read all words from `inputFile` and store them as a sequence of `std::string`s in the vector `words`. Since you file contains numbers you might want to replace `std::string` by `int` to read numbers in a readily accessible form.
2. If you want to read a line rather than a word you can use [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) instead:

   ```
   if (std::getline(inputFile, line)) { ... }
   ```

   If you want to read multiple lines, you'd put this operation into a loop: There is, unfortunately, no read-made approach to read a sequence of lines as there is for words.
3. If you want to read the entire file, not just the first line, into a file, you can also use `std::getline()` but you'd need to know about one character value which doesn't occur in your file, e.g., the null value:

   ```
   if (std::getline(inputFile, text, char()) { ... }
   ```

   This approach considers a "line" a sequence of characters up to a null character. You can use any other character value as well. If you can't be sure about the character values, you can read an entire file using `std::string`'s constructor taking iterators:

   ```
   std::string text((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(inputFile)),
                    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
   ```

   Note, that the extra pair of parenthesis around the first parameter is, unfortunately, necessary (if you are using C++ 2011 you can avoid them by using braces, instead of parenthesis).

Comment: the problem is when i use the method you mentioned above for reading the entire file using string constructors that take iterators, the string i use seems too small to contain all 100 numbers. It only contains the last 19 numbers of the set. I encountered this problem when I tried to use getLine() methode as well. As far as i remember a string automatically resizes itself when needed, but that does not seem to work for me.

Comment: The constructor definitely reads the entire file! I can't even come up with a plausible reason for reading only the tail of the input! Can you show what you are doing?

Comment: ifstream inputFile("text.txt");

string s((istreambuf_iterator<char>(inputFile)), istreambuf_iterator<char>());
i tried this, but apparently the cause of my problem is due to a bug in my IDE. It may capture the whole line and put it in a string with no problem but the problem occurs when it displays the string. My IDE's (netbeans) output panel is capable of displaying a certain size of string. Before printing the string containing these numbers if i print some other stuff using cout they just overlap each other instead of continuing a new line.

Answer (score 2):

Use **[getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/)** to do the reading.

```
string numbers;
if (inputFile.is_open())//checking if open
{
      getline (inputFile,numbers); //fetches entire line into string numbers
      inputFile.close();
}
```

Comment: I tried using that but this time it game a string party different than my text file. My text file is this 
3 5 2 13 4 5 6 7 1 7
5 13 12 2 7 12 3 1 4 5
1 10 5 1 14 6 4 1 7 2
4 9 17 5 6 2 7 21 8 1
6 17 32 8 5 4 1 4 3 34
7 6 85 20 2 6 13 6 72 2
1 1 97 3 1 9 5 48 1 8
3 23 3 34 16 1 51 192 4 6
6 25 2 12 3 3 3 4 219 5
12 53 8 73 4 17 14 7 8 22

and what i got is
12      53      87      73      46      17      14      792     819     22

seems like the last bit of my text file but slightly different

Answer (score -1):

Your program does behave exactly as in your description : `inputFile >> numbers;` just extract the first integer in the input file, so if you suppress the tab, `inputFile>>` will extract the number `12345`, not 5 five numbers `[1,2,3,4,5]`.

a better method :

```
vector< int > numbers;
string fileName = "text.txt";
ifstream inputFile;
inputFile.open(fileName.c_str(),ios_base::in);
char c;
while (inputFile.good())     // loop while extraction from file is possible
{
    c = inputFile.get();       // get character from file
    if ( inputFile.good() and c!= '\t' and c!=' ' ) // not sure of tab and space encoding in C++
    {
      numbers.push_back( (int) c);
    }
}
inputFile.close();
```